# Too few arguments to function Admin::edituser1(), 0 passed in C:\wamp64\www\pg\system\core\CodeIgniter.php on line 532 and exactly 1 expected

Tags: php, codeigniter, error-handling, codeigniter-3

I'm getting an error while editing a user

controller

```
  public function edituser1($id)

 {
 $this->load->model('loginmodel');

 $userid=$this->loginmodel->find_user($id); 

 $this->load->view('Admin/edituser1',['userid'=>$userid]);

 }
```

view

```
  <th><?=  anchor("Admin/edituser1/{$art->id}",'Edit',['class'=>'btn btn-success']);  ?></th>
```

it's updating the details but after that giving me an error

> Too few arguments to function Admin::edituser1(), 0 passed in C:\wamp64\www\pg\system\core\CodeIgniter.php on line 532 and exactly 1 expected

Comment: Please edit the question instead of commenting, also are you certain that `$art->id` is not empty?

Comment: yea i'm not really seeing how it could update correctly and still give you that error unless you directly access the function without the last param...

Comment: $art->id is fetching data..it's not empty

Comment: it it is not empty and your database updates, I'm not sure how you are getting that error without directly accessing the function. either way doing `function edituser1($id = null)` is common practice. and testing for null to see if you have the required params.